# how to build a predicate/expression/rule/action engine

Tags: javascript, php, expression, predicate

Okay so first off, sorry for the TL;DR...

2nd, some context about what I want to achieve.

I have a script that processes a given file and generates a new file based on a defined set of rules. Each row in the file has a value and the script evaluates the value and generates other values based on that value and rules in general. The generated file contains the original value and the generated values in csv format.

For example:

**input file:**

```
row1value
row2value
```

**output file:**

```
"row1value","generatedValue1","generatedValue2","generatedValue3"
"row2value","generatedValue1","generatedValue2","generatedValue3"
```

For example, lets say the source file has a colon delimited value on each row, and the goal is to split the value by the colon and put each sub-value into the columns. This is what the "before" and "after" would look like:

**input file:**

```
a:b:c
some:random:value
```

**output file:**

```
"a:b:c","a","b","c"
"some:random:value","some","random","value"
```

So to generate the rows, I might have:

```
function generateRow ($key) {
  // $key is the value for the current row being processed from the source file
  // $row is the array that will contain the columns to be inserted to the output file
  $row = array();

  // generate the column values
  $row = explode(":",$key);

  // make the original value ($key) the first column
  array_unshift($row, $key);

  // return the array. some other function will fputcsv it
  return $row;
}
```

Another example would be if the source file contains rows of values like this:

`[prefix]:[url]`

And the values for the columns in the output file would be:

- column1 = full original value (it will always be this)
- column2 = `[prefix]`
- column3 = [url]
- column4 = parse [url] for the domain of the url
- column5 = parse [url] for the file extension

So I write `generateRow()` to do these things.

Okay so I have all this. It is all shiny and working great.  I get requests to make new "processes" that receive their own file and generate a new file with columns based on defined rules.  I just wanted to provide all this as backstory to put this into context so that y'all would more easily understand what I actually want.

So the "problem" is that as it stands, the "process" is made by a coder (me) writing out `generateRow()` based on the specs.  This isn't particularly difficult for myself or anybody else who knows php.  But this is not "user friendly" in that certain stakeholders want to be in charge of creating this stuff on their own, but they are not coders.

So my task now is to basically provide a web interface for `generateRow()`.  So the way I see it, I basically need to make a form that dynamically generates form elements and possible options based on previously selected items.  In other words, an expression engine. Or predicate engine. Or rule builder. Honestly I'm not 100% sure which, if any, of these terms is the most accurate, but I've been doing a lot of googling and reading and so far these are what I've come up with.

So for example, the form would start out with asking the user to create a condition or assignment expression,

[dropdown:if|set]

**IF:** If the user clicks "if" then another dropdown displays with a list of "variables" to check against.  For example the system will have available as selects a reference to the other columns, any column from the source file (including the key), the import file name, or any custom variable a user previously made (see "set" below). The form will then show an "action" dropdown, that will display things like "is set","not set","greater than","regex",etc. If the user selects something like "is set" or "not set" then no other fields are output. But if the user selects for instance "greater than", then another dropdown will show, asking to select from the list of "variables", or an input field to enter in a value.  Examples:

```
IF column1 "is set"           /* check if column1 is set */
IF column1 contains "foobar"  /* check if column1 contains "foobar" */
If column1 regex "^[a-z]+$"   /* check if column1 contains only letters */
```

Once this is defined, user can add "set" expressions inside it.  For simplicity I don't think i need to nest conditions or use AND|OR to make compound conditions.

**SET:** So if user selects this option, the form will guide them through building an assignment expression.  The first dropdown will hold the variables the user can assign values to, such as the columns for the output file, or temporary variables so that they can be referenced in other expressions. Examples:

```
SET [column1] [=] ["foobar"]
SET [column2] [=] [column1]
SET [column1] [regex] [userVar1] ["^[^:]+"]
SET [userVar1] [explode] [key] [":"]
```

Well I'm not sure that's the "best" way to present it but hopefully you get the idea.

Then I would save these expressions and then write php code to evaluate them; basically translate them into actual php code.  I think I'm actually fine as far as that part: I would just use an interpreter pattern.

But where I need help on is the whole expression "mapping" / "builder" part.  Actually I think i can even swing the "builder" part, if I can get a "mapping" of possible expressions fleshed out.

**So yeah, that's where the core of my question lays: how to map out possible expressions.** Currently I've been playing around with trying to structure/map it as xml, but I can't seem to grasp how to do it, short of just hardcoding every possible path. Firstly, to me this seems kinda inefficient, like there should be a smarter way to do it. It can't possibly be easily scalable... let's say "process" #1's ruleset has 2 source file columns to draw from and 5 output file columns to generate.. and "process" #2's is 1 and 4? What about accounting for variable amount of user defined variables a user can set.

So, does anybody have any tips or links to tuts explaining how to do this sort of thing? Or better yet a prefab (php) solution would be nice, but I haven't been able to find something yet..

**edit:** here is an example of where I am now, to hopefully give a better understanding of my problem.

For example, here's how it woulda sorta go down if i were to just hardcode a map (xml)

```
<expressions>
  <expression type='if'>
    <variable name='column1'>
      <operator type='isset'></operator>
      <operator type='notset'></operator> 
      <operator type='equals'>
        <variable name='column1' />
        <variable name='column2' />
        <variable name='column3' />
      </operator>
      <operator type='greaterThan'>
        <variable name='column1' />
        <variable name='column2' />
        <variable name='column3' />
      </operator>
      <operator type='lessThan'>
        <variable name='column1' />
        <variable name='column2' />
        <variable name='column3' />
      </operator>
    </variable>
    <variable name='column2'>
      <operator type='equals'>
        <variable name='column1' />
        <variable name='column2' />
        <variable name='column3' />
      </operator>
      <operator type='greaterThan'>
        <variable name='column1' />
        <variable name='column2' />
        <variable name='column3' />
      </operator>
      <operator type='lessThan'>
        <variable name='column1' />
        <variable name='column2' />
        <variable name='column3' />
      </operator>
    </variable>
</expressions>
```

Couple notes:

1. there are an arbitrary number of `variable` nodes. There will be one for each source file column, one for each output file column name, one for each variable the user creates on-the-fly, etc..
2. there are a variable number of `operator` types.  I just showed 3 examples, but so far I have like 20 that i've thought of
3. Notice how some of the `operator` types would require additional form fields to be output on the form.  For example, "if [column1] [isset]" vs. "if [column1] [greaterThan] [column2]"
4. The `expression` node shows what the "if" expression would look like. There would also be a an `expression` node of type "set" which would have a different structure but in principle work the same. For example there could be an expression "[set] [column2] [equals] [column1]" or "[set] [column1] [regex] [sourceColumn1] [input value (regex)]"

So right now I can just walk down the path to dynamically build menus based on what's available going down the tree.

But as you can see, it seems like there's a lot of repetition, and also it would be a pita to throw new things into the mix (like a new operator). So the question here is, how would I structure this better? Or is it just not possible, and the only solution is to just hardcode every possibility?

Comment: break the problem down into pieces. write a generic row parser that has no hard-coded values in it, everything needed being passed as arguments. then, one-by-one, delete formal parameters and replace with a top-of-function var pointing to a form input's value instead of an argument, leaving the local name the same. ex (age, height){} would become (height){var age=ages.value;} after 1 step. you can hard-code form values/options at first to get it running, then figure out how to populate your form automatically based upon the input file. one step at a time...

Comment: @dandavis thanks for the response! I'm not quite sure I understand what you are suggesting..I think I already have a plan for parsing the expressions, and I'm pretty sure I can work out dynamically populating the form - assuming I have a map of what possible combinations there are.  So what I'm actually stuck on is how to structure the map itself.  The *easy* way would be to just hardcode all the possibilities somewhere (array/object, db struture, xml file).

Comment: But all tedium aside, it's not a very scalable solution. If I think of a new "operator" to add, I'd have to go through and add it to every applicable branch. That doesn't really seem efficient to me. It seems the answer lies somewhere in having nodes backward and forward reference other nodes, but I've not quite worked out how to actually do that?

Comment: Perhaps what you're *really* trying to do is think of a way to represent the AST (Abstract Syntax Tree) for your language.

Comment: I don't understand your question. You transform an input file according to a set of rules (conditions / assignations), but what is the purpose of the tree? Can't you, when adding a field, parse again previous rules to dynamically set all dropdown values (for values of a variable for example)? A tree should be used on much harder stuffs, where there are brackets for example.

Comment: the purpose of the tree is to store the possible form field values for a given expression. For example, if a user chooses `if` then the next dropdown will have a list of "variables" they can use for comparison.  But if a user chooses `set` then the dropdown list will only show the variables they can actually set.  For example there might options to represent the source file's name or other information contained in the header of the source file. The user will be able to base rules on those things, but not actually set those variables.

Comment: @AlainTiemblo another example: if a user selects `if [variable] [isset]` then no additional form field would be output.  But if the user selects `if [variable] [contains]` then the next form field to be output would be an input field or dropdown of available variables (combobox)

Comment: so basically the purpose of the tree is the script can know the next form element and values, if any, it should output, based on what the user has done before.  IOW the tree is supposed to represent all the possible expressions a user can make

Answer (score 3):

Wow, this is a great question! I'll start off with answers to your direct questions and then touch on general issues.

If you want off the shelf products for this, there are "product configuration" systems such as 3dfacto's or possibly Drools that take a set of rules (in this case, rules for how your system's rules are constructed) and can create a dynamic form that only permits entering valid rules. It's actually not a whole lot different from the XML you wrote above. Let's take a look at what's going on:

First, you're defining a language to express the rules in your system. The structure of your language is called the grammar and we typically use BNF to describe grammars. For example:

```
command := <if> | <set>
if := "if" <boolexpr> "then" <command>
boolexpr := <column> isset |
            <column> notset | 
            <column> "greaterThan" <column> |
            <column> "lessThan" <column>
<column> := "column1" | "column2" | ... | "column_n"
set := <column> <equals> <value> | ...
value := <column> | <number>
```

Note that some parts of the grammar may need to involve code. For instance, the "columns" part is dynamic depending on # of actual columns. You can [take a look at the grammar](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/drools/tree/master/drools-compiler/src/main/resources/org/drools/compiler/lang) for the Drools rule engine, although there's a lot of code mixed in.

The key difference between a BNF representation of a grammar and the XML map is something you've hit on: forward and backwards links. The two represent the exact same thing, however the BNF is more compact than the XML. This is because sub-structures can be referenced rather than copied as-is. For example, we can use the `<value>` rule wherever we don't care whether it's a column or a literal number. Another way to think of it is that there are many more paths through the rules than there are rules.

How do we represent a grammar in code? One way is to use arrays.

```
$column = a_function
$boolexpr = Array("or", Array("match", $column, "isset"), Array("match", $column, "notset"), Array("match", $column, "greatherthan", $column), Array("match", $column, "lessthan", $column))
$command_grammar = Array("match", "If", $boolexpr, "then", $command)
```

Your form builder system will essentially be doing abstract interpretation on this grammar. You're asking: "giving the input up to this point, what are the valid next inputs?" And you do that by interpreting the grammar with the rule as entered thus far, and seeing what comes next. You mentioned the "interpreter" pattern so I think you're familiar with this.

Another way to think of it is you're making a parser. Normally, a parser tries every possible path through the grammar rules attempting to match against the input, and rejects any path as soon as:

1. The input and the path thus far differs
2. The path has finished but there's more input remaining.
3. The input has finished but there's further non-empty grammar rules along the path.

In your system, (1) and (2) can never happen because you don't allow entering an invalid rule. (3) can happen because the user hasn't fully specified the rule, so you can look at what grammar rules come next to update the form.

Lets take a step back and look at what we're trying to do: allow non-programmers to program the computer. One frequent issue is that attempts to make such systems flexible lead to them becoming their own programming language. And usually they're worse than existing languages, and then you need to be a programmer to use it. I think you have the right idea by saying some things, like "or" would be too complicated. Limiting the complexity avoids this turing tarpit.

Another approach to avoiding the problem is to leverage your existing language, like PHP. You can define functions that make the task easier, and have the end-user directly write PHP using your examples as guides. Continuous feedback helps here. Take a look at [Processing](http://processing.org/) for an example of this approach.

Comment: I'm not sure that this properly answers my question, but I think maybe it is because of my own failure to properly explain what I'm trying to solve. This was by far the most helpful response, so i awarded the bounty to you. I'm actually wondering now if I even need to represent the possible expressions in an xml file (or db structure or w/e). I'm going to have to write the logic for parsing it using interpreter pattern anyways.  I guess I just thought if I had a "map" in a separate file, I could draw from that for the parser, but then also draw from it and then use javascript to ...

Comment: ... do the work of dynamically build the form.  So IOW js would build the form based on the "map", and would send then the user saves the built expression. php would parse the expression and perform the actions based on it (e.g. conditions and assignments).  I wrote a "proof of concept" script around this and overall it is fine.. but my issue really is scalability. My proof of concept just uses 3 hardcoded variables/columns and like 5 operators.  Everything works fine but it's canned. As you can see in my example, there is a lot of repetition in places and it just seems like there should be ..

Comment: .. a better way to do it.

Comment: I agree with you that a separately defined grammar is ideal, but much more work than directly creating the parser and builder. If the grammar for your rules language doesn't change often, I wouldn't bother. When hard-coding the parser and form system, can you use functions to abstract repetitive parts? If that sounds like what you're after, let me know: I can edit my answer to discuss this.

Comment: On the other hand, you also appear interested in continuing to use an XML to describe the grammar, and have a proof of concept of that, but wish it were more compact and less repetitive. I could expand on this as well.

Comment: well, i just thought that having the "map" separate like in an xml file would make it easier for both the backend (the php parser using interpreter pattern) and the front end (using javascript to dynamically build the form elements and options).  Especially if I were to say, add a new operator later on down the line, then I wouldn't have to go and update 2 sets of code. I'm certainly up for alternate suggestions...

Comment: but in reality I don't think adding a new condition or assignment "operator" is going to happen much, so I'm not opposed to just toughing it out and building out a hardcoded map..however, my main concern is the 3 "variable sets" that are dynamic: # of columns, custom vars and source file columns.  There can be any number of columns from the source file so each one of them would have to be mapped with the possible condition and assignment routes. Same with the output columns and user defined variables.  That's the main sticking point for me.. whether there's 3 columns or 10 columns, there...

Comment: ... they will all have the same possible map routes, but how to make it dynamically assign them? I'm thinking i may have to have a "template" route for each one, for each part of the map they show up in and then write a script to update the map file.  This probably isn't too bad for the source and output columns because those are generally established before the creation of the tool so it's generally a "1 time" thing (though sometimes business requirements may change and it has to be updated, but rarely). The real sticking point is the user vars that can be created on-the-fly. I was ...

Comment: .. thinking the *easy* route to take would just be to only allow a set number (like 5) but I was hoping there was a relatively easy way to not have to enforce a limit.

Answer (score 1):

OKAY , as i understood, u want a rule generation system , so user send the main string or file and says  what he wants , then rule generator make the rules based on user wants  , then send them as rules to generateRow() , then generateRow() return the value(s);

1- as u said , u must define the main operation rules such as equal, GT , LT , or contains , regExp , and etc as an possible array and group them as they type, for example regExp or contains use in strings , so we have 2 group of operation rules here , strings , numbers . then make a xml file with this groups and notes . make a note for every operator like :

```
<strings>
 <oprator>
  <title>equal</title>
  <php_func>stristr</php_func>
  <input_arg_count>2</input_arg_count>
  <true_return>true</true_return>
 </oprator>

 <oprator>
  <title>not_in</title>
  <php_func>stristr</php_func>
  <input_arg_count>2</input_arg_count>
  <true_return>false</true_return>
 </oprator>

</string>
```

3- u must ask from user what type is ur input file , pile or column based , if col based , what is  the columns divider character , example , or | or :

2- in user interface , u must ask the columns type which will be under operation. for example col1 type : string . col2 type : int , if the user input is based on cols . else if user input file is just pile file , the rule generator must set to string . else must set to special rules group by user set data , example if col1 is string , set possible operators into string operators, the show the user string operators.

3- some operators must have 2 input arguments (input_arg_count)  , so   u must divide ask about columns , which cols must be  operate in this operation

4- u must collect every user rules with inputs (better use string) the send it to rule generator as operation string.

5- rule generator with divide the operation string ( by ur defined dividers ),  then in  switchs , make rules.

6- switch  : in this switch must check the user input file type , if pile , call ur pile class , if col based call col based class , even u can make pile file a col based file by first operator , axample , if firs operator is has | so , u can devide the file by | , then u have a col based file. this will rediuse the operations

7- then check the operation tyle , so in posible oprators xml file,  u can understand the type of operation .  and make a main function that get the oprators as array and  as another argument get the operator , and as last argument get the usable php function from posible operators xml file . so the system will now which function , which oprator and arguments.

8- after returning the resulat of first operation . send into next operation , like loop function , so the operations will be operat.

u can put it into git hub , so i can help u to develop it .

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

If as in your examples the original value is always a string and the rules always some modifications on that string such that the generated values are always deductible from only the string, have you thought about a machine learning approach? You could get the user to fill out examples of the original value and generated values, and your algorithm could try to infer the rules from the examples.

[This paper](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/sumitg/pubs/semantic.pdf) seems to be doing something like what you want (but perhaps slightly more complicated; if all your rules are basically regexes, it might be easier).

This option should be scalable and if you can find the right algorithm it should minimize the need for you to do busywork, but it's not perfect, and if you go for that kind of approach there might be a user at some point who has some really complicated rule that needs to be handwritten.